# Does $\frac{8k-1}{4}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

Does $\frac{8k-1}{4}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ ? or we can prove that this never belongs to  $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: $$\frac{8k}{4} - \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: This was so easy :) I am having a bad day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{8k - 1}{4} = 2k - \frac 1 4$$

Answer (score 0):

$8k-1$ is a 1 less than a multiple of 4, so it can't be divisible by 4.